# What is Terredo

Tags: router, port-forwarding

So my router was acting up so I decided to take a look at it. When I looked at the port forwarding rules I found about 300 Terredo port forwards. When I deleted them everything worked fine on my router and on my computer. I did so research and all I could find is that Terredo has something to do with ipv6 and tunneling, I can not find anything more. Can someone please tell me what it is besides the fact that it has something to do with ipv6 and tunneling. I would also like to know how to disable it.

Comment: You need to find out which program is using Terredo to open up ports in your router.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That is irrelevant. Windows sets up the tunnel automatically, programs cannot ask for it.

Comment: @grawity utorrent does [something special with Teredo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OkvYI.png), I don't know what it is doing though.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: It does **nothing more** than install general IPv6 support system-wide (including Teredo), like `netsh interface ipv6 install`. The button is there because Windows XP didn't have IPv6 support enabled by default. After enabling IPv6, however, all tunnels (6to4, Teredo, ISATAP) are set up automatically.

Comment: @grawity after reading your answer I came to that conclusion on my own too (good answer +1 btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Teredo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) <sup>(one 'r')</sup> is an IPv6-over-IPv4 tunnel; in other words, it's a method to give IPv6 connectivity when your ISP only provides IPv4. It works by putting all IPv6 packets inside UDP and sending them over IPv4 to a "proxy" server at Microsoft, which resends them directly over IPv6.

There really isn't much more to say about it. Windows automatically sets up a tunnel when it doesn't find a native IPv6 connection, using 6to4 when possible and Teredo otherwise.

To disable Teredo on Windows XP and later, run this command:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set teredo disable
```

To re-enable Teredo (which you probably will never need):

```
netsh interface ipv6 set teredo client teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com
```

(I won't describe how to disable IPv6 itself, because that is not necessary.)